# How to run more than one tcl scripts at the same time

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, tcl

I want to run four tcl at the same time. In shell, I can use "&" to run. Is there something in tcl like "&" to run concurrently? I just want to run four independent tcl in one terminal and don't want to use multi-thread.

Comment: Its not really clear what your trying to do, are you running 4 TCL programs from the shell in which case you've already mentioned the & command or do you want to run 4 TCL sub processes from within TCL in which case command pipelines and channel events may be what you want - see the open and chan commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run things concurrently, you have to either use multiple processes or multiple threads (or multiple computers). The `&` with the shell uses the multiprocess approach. In Tcl, you can use `&` too, but only with the `exec` command that launches subprocesses (it also has to be the *last* argument IIRC). Assuming you've put your code into four Tcl scripts, `a.tcl`, `b.tcl`, `c.tcl`, and `d.tcl`, then you'd launch them all in parallel with this:

```
exec [info nameofexecutable] a.tcl &
exec [info nameofexecutable] b.tcl &
exec [info nameofexecutable] c.tcl &
exec [info nameofexecutable] d.tcl &
```

There might be a few more details to do with passing any parameters over and setting up stdio redirections, but that's about it.

You can also use threads, which is approximately just doing this:

```
package require Thread

thread::create [list source a.tcl]
thread::create [list source b.tcl]
thread::create [list source c.tcl]
thread::create [list source d.tcl]
```

There's a few details to do with handling detecting when all the scripts are done, but it's not exactly complicated.

Comment: The `info nameofexecutable` command returns the fully-qualified name of the program running Tcl, so perhaps `/usr/bin/tclsh8.6` or `C:/Tcl/tclsh86.exe`. It's very useful in cases like this.

Comment: It's also possible to write code that interleaves processing of scripts within a single thread of a single process. It has to be carefully written to make that possible though, and is a significantly more advanced technique than what you're used to.